# How to know which minions failed to execute a Salt state

Tags: salt-stack

suppose I am running:

```
salt '*' state.highstate
```

over a great number of minions.

I get some output for each of them with information about the statuses run and a short summary at the end (succeded, failed, total).

My problem is that, since output is so large, I am unable to tell at a glance if any of the minions failed on some statuses. I could of course redirect the output to a text file and search it or grep it but I would really appreciate some kind of "gross summary" at the end of every execution that told me how many and which nodes failed.

Is there any way to do that that I have been overlooking? I haven't been able to find anything on the Internet.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options that might give you the type of output you want.

First, if you add a `-v` to your command you'll get more info on which minions didn't respond, etc.

Second, in your master config try setting `state_output: mixed`. This will give you a short one-liner for states that were successful, and the full output for states that failed. This should make it a bit easier to find the failed states.

Third, in your master config set `state_verbose: False` and that will cause Salt to only display failed states.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply; all of your suggestions are useful to tidy up the output but I still have to scroll or search or grep in order to find which (if any) minions have failed. Consider that I have more than one hundred minions! :p

Comment: `state_verbose: False` will only show you failures, if that's what you need.

Comment: I tried `state_verbose: False` but it is still creating 5-6 lines of output for each minion. Having a large number of minions a lot of screens get filled very fast!
Am I doing something wrong? I tried to restart salt-master after changing the configuration but the output doesn't change.